# Excel interop in C# faster to read big Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, performance, bigdata, interop

Please can anyone try to tell me what shall I change in my code to get faster reading of Excel files?

I have 9 000 rows in my Excel sheet. I will have to work with more Excel files which have even more rows and I think my solution is very slow. Now I read Excel (9000 rows) read second and one (800 rows) then I do compare values (trying to find that 800 records in 9000 rows. It take me over 100sec on two separate threads.

```
class ExcelParser
{
    private string path;
     _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
    Workbook wb;
    Worksheet ws;
    private int Sheet;

    public ExcelParser(string path, int Sheet)
    {
        this.Sheet = Sheet;
        this.path = path;
        this.wb = this.excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
        this.ws = wb.Worksheets[Sheet];
    }

    //column code and available are index of excel  column from where read data
    public Dictionary<string, string> ReadCell(int column_code = 0, int column_available = 0)
    {
        int i = 2; // row index in excel
        Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        try { 
        while (this.ws.Cells[i, column_code].Value2 != null)
        {
            try
            {
                data.Add(this.ws.Cells[i, column_code].Value2, (this.ws.Cells[i, column_available].Value2).ToString());
                i++;

                }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                i++;
                //form_obj.UpdateText(i);
            }

        }
        } finally {
            wb.Close();
            excel.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excel);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(this.ws);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(this.wb);
            this.ws = null;
            this.wb = null;
        }
        return data;

    }
}
```

Also my GUI keeps open 3 Excel instances, after I release all objects or try to `this.wb.Close()`. After I quit the GUI, the instances are exited. Why are instances of Excel not closed after this function ends via  `wb.Close();` and `excel.Quit();`?

Comment: I don't know how to address your speed issue other than suggesting that you abandon Interop for a solution using the OpenXML spec. As to why your instances of Excel are not closed when you expect them to be, I believe this is because .NET handles its own garbage collection in its own time, so items may not be disposed of when you think they should.

Comment: Reading Excel spreadsheets a cell at a time is always slow. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/42604291/34092

Comment: Your use of `FinalReleaseComObject` isn't thorough enough to be useful either, since you aren't releasing _all_ of the objects. https://ausdotnet.wordpress.com/